# Trouble with eigenvalue proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am having a lot of trouble trying to prove a statement in linear algebra,

il post it and what I have tried etc,

Let $A \in \mathbb M_{nxn}$ and let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_r$ be distinct eigenvalues of A,

Let $S_1=\{v_1^1,...,v_{k1}^1\}, ..., S_r=\{v_1^r,...,v_{kr}^r\}$ and suppose that the $S_i$ are linearly independent for $i=1,..,r$ and that $S_i \subset E_{\lambda i}$ (eigenspace)

Show that the set $\{v_1^1,...,v_{k1}^1,....,v_1^r,...v_{kr}^r\}$ is linearly independent.

Overall I am really confused, I do know that and how to prove that eigenvectors are linearly independent if they all have distinct eigenvalues. But I am not sure how to compare it with this, secondly, all the notation is a little confusing and I am having trouble even understand what I need to show. For example what is the diffirence between $v_1^1$ and $v_1^r$?

I think it can maybe be done with showing all the coefficients are zero.

Any suggestions or hints to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you split the proof into two parts.

**Theorem.** *If $x_1\in E_{\lambda_1},x_2\in E_{\lambda_2},\dots,x_k\in E_{\lambda_k}$ for pairwise distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k$ and $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=0$, then $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_k=0$.*

*Proof.* Induction on $k$. The case $k=1$ is obvious. Suppose the result is true for $k-1$ vectors. Then we have
\begin{gather}
0=A(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k)=
\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\dots+\lambda_kx_k
\\
0=\lambda_k(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k)=
\lambda_kx_1+\lambda_kx_2+\dots+\lambda_kx_k
\end{gather}
Subtracting the two relations, we get
$$
0=(\lambda_1-\lambda_k)x_1+(\lambda_2-\lambda_k)x_2+\dots+(\lambda_{k-1}-\lambda_k)x_{k-1}
$$
and, by the induction hypothesis, we get
$$
(\lambda_1-\lambda_k)x_1=0\\
(\lambda_2-\lambda_k)x_2=0\\
\dots\\
(\lambda_{k-1}-\lambda_k)x_{k-1}=0
$$
So $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_{k-1}=0$ and hence also $x_k=0$. QED

Now you should be able to conclude, by invoking the theorem above. Instead of the complicated notation, write
\begin{align}
S_1&=\{v_{1,1},\dots,v_{1,k_1}\},\\
\dots,\\
S_r&=\{v_{r,1},\dots,v_{r,k_r}\}
\end{align}
A zero linear combination can be written
$$
\underbrace{\alpha_{1,1}v_{1,1}+\dots+\alpha_{1,k_1}v_{1,k_1}}_{\in E_{\lambda_1}}
+
\underbrace{\alpha_{2,1}v_{2,1}+\dots+\alpha_{2,k_2}v_{2,k_2}}_{\in E_{\lambda_1}}
+
\dots
+
\underbrace{\alpha_{r,1}v_{r,1}+\dots+\alpha_{r,k_r}v_{r,k_r}}_{\in E_{\lambda_r}}
=0
$$
and you can set
\begin{align}
x_1&=\alpha_{1,1}v_{1,1}+\dots+\alpha_{1,k_1}v_{1,k_1}\\
x_2&=\alpha_{2,1}v_{2,1}+\dots+\alpha_{2,k_2}v_{2,k_2}\\
\dots\\
x_r&=\alpha_{r,1}v_{r,1}+\dots+\alpha_{r,k_r}v_{r,k_r}
\end{align}
so invoking the above theorem and then the linear independence of the subsets you're done.

Comment: thanks a lot for the effort, I just have a few question, what is meant by "pairwise"? are you basically saying for the eigenvalue 1 there is one eigenvector $x_1$, for the eigen value k , there is one eigenvector $x_k$ etc?$

Comment: And secondly, is the way you concoluded that x_k would be zero is beaucause you used the fact that all the others were 0, so it would essentialy be the same as $0+0+..+( \lambda _r - \lambda _{r+1})=0$ ?

Comment: @PersonaA I mean that $\lambda_i\ne\lambda_j$, for $i\ne j$. When you have proved that $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_{k-1}=0$, you get, from the first relation $x_1+\dots+x_{k-1}+x_k=0$, that also $x_k=0$.

Comment: Thank you. And why is that we use x first as well? do they still correspond to the eigenvectors?

Comment: also how can you have that xk for example=0, i thought eigenvectors cant be 0,  ( but I do know that 0 is in the eigenspace)

Comment: @PersonaA The eigenspace is a subspace; eigenvectors are by definition nonzero, but I'm taking $x_i$ in the eigenspace $E_{\lambda_i}$, so it can be $0$. Note that I didn't mention eigenvectors exactly for this. We have $E_\lambda=\{v: Av=\lambda v\}$ and $0$ surely satisfies the condition (as well as the eigenvectors).

Comment: Okay thanks, by the way when you say by the induction hypothesis, is that allowed because $ (\lambda_1 - \lambda_k)x_1$ is also in the eigenspace?

Comment: @PersonaA Yes, that's it: the eigenspace is a subspace, so it contains all scalar multiples of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sum_{k,j} r_{kj}v_{kj} = 0$. Rewrite this sum as
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_j\left(\sum_k r_{kj}v_{kj}\right).
\end{equation*}
Each term in the outer sum is a sum of elements of $S_j$, so it is in $S_j$. But the $S_j$ are linearly independent subspaces since they correspond to different eigenvalues, so each sum is zero. Now use linear independence of $v_{1j}, \dotsc, v_{kj}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$\alpha^i_1v^i_1+\cdots +\alpha^i_{k_i}v^i_{k_i}$ is a $\lambda_i$-eigenvalue of $A$ for any $\alpha^i_1, \cdots,\alpha^i_{k_i}\in \mathbb{R}.$